# Select sentence having a selected word in it

Tags: python, nltk

Suppose i have a paragraph:

```
text = '''Darwin published his theory of evolution with compelling evidence in his 1859 book On the Origin of Species, overcoming scientific rejection of earlier concepts of transmutation of species.[4][5] By the 1870s the scientific community and much of the general public had accepted evolution as a fact. However, many favoured competing explanations and it was not until the emergence of the modern evolutionary synthesis from the 1930s to the 1950s that a broad consensus developed in which natural selection was the basic mechanism of evolution.[6][7] In modified form, Darwin's scientific discovery is the unifying theory of the life sciences, explaining the diversity of life.[8][9]'''
```

If say i enter a word (favoured), then how can i remove the entire sentence the word is in.
The method i used earlier was tedious; i would use sent_tokenize to break the para (which is over 13000 words) and since i had to check for more than 1000 words, i would run a loop to check for each word in each sentence. This takes a lot of time as there are over 400 sentences.

Instead i want to check for those 1000 words in the para, and when the word is found it selects all words before till full stop and all words after, till full stop.

Comment: What about a sentence that doesn't end in a period? You want to remove the first sentence the word is in, or all sentences the word is in?

Comment: Are you using NLTK? If so, you should add that as a tag...

Comment: `''.join([sentence for sentence in text.split('.') if 'favoured' not in sentence])`

Comment: As in my question my dictionary for selecting words is around 1000 words, so your method will take forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes all sentences (things bounded by a `.`) that contain the word somewhere.

```
def remove_sentence(input, word):
    return ".".join((sentence for sentence in input.split(".")
                    if word not in sentence))

>>>> remove_sentence(text, "published")
"[4][5] By the 1870s the scientific community and much of the general public had accepted evolution as a fact. However, many favoured competing explanations and it was not until the emergence of the modern evolutionary synthesis from the 1930s to the 1950s that a broad consensus developed in which natural selection was the basic mechanism of evolution.[6][7] In modified form, Darwin's scientific discovery is the unifying theory of the life sciences, explaining the diversity of life.[8][9]"
>>>
>>> remove_sentence(text, "favoured")
"Darwin published his theory of evolution with compelling evidence in his 1859 book On the Origin of Species, overcoming scientific rejection of earlier concepts of transmutation of species.[4][5] By the 1870s the scientific community and much of the general public had accepted evolution as a fact.[6][7] In modified form, Darwin's scientific discovery is the unifying theory of the life sciences, explaining the diversity of life.[8][9]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand you question, but you can do something like:

```
text = 'whatever....'
sentences = text.split('.')
good_sentences = [e for e in sentences if 'my_word' not in e]
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah i did that but you see my 'whatever...' is HUGE and my_word are multiple. So if i have one word 1000 sentences, then i do 1000 iterations, but if i have 10 words ten sentences, then i have 10000 iterations. And this takes time.

Comment: You'll still have to go through all of your sentences. List comprehensions make it faster. Or try using [pypy](http://pypy.org/) to make it even faster

Comment: My example uses a generator comprehension. This may be quicker than a list comprehension as it doesn't need to allocate a massive amount of memory. Test it.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a bit faster, indeed

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in trying something similar to the following program:

```
import re

SENTENCES = ('This is a sentence.',
             'Hello, world!',
             'Where do you want to go today?',
             'The apple does not fall far from the tree.',
             'Sally sells sea shells by the sea shore.',
             'The Jungle Book has several stories in it.',
             'Have you ever been up to the moon?',
             'Thank you for helping with my problem!')

BAD_WORDS = frozenset(map(str.lower, ('to', 'sea')))

def main():
    for index, sentence in enumerate(SENTENCES):
        if frozenset(words(sentence.lower())) & BAD_WORDS:
            print('Delete:', repr(sentence))

words = lambda sentence: (m.group() for m in re.finditer('\w+', sentence))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Reason

1. You start out with the sentences that you want to filter and the words you want to find.
2. You compare each sentence's set of words with the set of words you are looking for.
3. If there was an intersection, the sentence you are looking at is one you will remove.

### Output

```
Delete: 'Where do you want to go today?'
Delete: 'Sally sells sea shells by the sea shore.'
Delete: 'Have you ever been up to the moon?'
```